# replacing elements of one array from others to minimize the sum of first array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

We are given two arrays , A[] of size n and another array B[] , of size  m , we can replace any number of elements in A[] , using elements of B[] , each element of B[] can be used only once to replace an element from array  A[].

what will be the minimum sum of array A[] after doing such replacements .

My Approach was to :

- sort array A and B
- replace elements from end of A with elements from front of B until element at front of B is less than element at end of A

However i am getting a WA with this approach.

Comment: What do you mean by WA?

Comment: @Irfan434 WA probably means "wrong answer" here

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm won't work. There is possibility that relatively larger elements will be remain in the final output array. I will post the relevant test-case here.

Just for now, I am telling what will work.

#### Solution #1

After sorting, this problem is just a sub-problem of merge sort. The is absolutely same as the merging step of merge sort.

- Sort `A` and `B`
- Merge `A` and `B` until the output array consists of `n` elements

The pseudo-code for merging will look like this:

```
function merge(int[] A, int[] B):
    n := length(A)
    m := length(B)
    int[] output := new int[n]
    i := 0
    j := 0
    k := 0
    while i < n and j < m and k < n do
        if A[i] <= B[j]
            output[k] := A[i]
            i := i + 1

        else if A[i] > B[j]
            output[k] := B[j]
            j := j + 1

        k := k + 1

    end


    while i < n and k < n do
        output[k] := A[i]
        i := i + 1
        k := k + 1
    end


    while j < m and k < n do
        output[k] := B[j]
        j := j + 1
        k := k + 1
    end

return output
```

Time complexity for sorting `O(nlogn)` and merging require `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space.

#### Solution #2 [Faster approach]

- Sort array `A` and `B`
- Take the `n` smallest elements by binary search approach. This is similar to the way of [finding median of two sorted array](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/). Here, instead of finding `median` you will go for `n` smallest elements and take all elements within this range in your output array.

Time complexity is `O(nlogn)` for sort and `O(log(n + m))` for second step.

Answer (score 0):

Answer would essentially be the smallest n numbers from n+m numbers from A and B.
Sort A - O(nlogn) and B - O(mlogm). Then using an approach similar to merge of mergesort algorithm, find the minimum n elements among these two sorted lists - O(n) and fill in array A